# Rails: render certain pins on a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each, pins

I would like to render only certain pins of my rails app on a page. 
Pins has a specific id. And I would like to render for example pin with id: 2 and 3 on a page and render pins with id 4 and 4 on an other page.

So i tried to implement this code on my controller in: **app/controller/pin_controller.rb**

```
def mypage
   @pin = Pin.find(2)
   @pin = Pin.find(3)
end
```

And in my **app/views/pins/mypage.html.erb** I inserted the **app/views/pins/index.html.erb**

to make it short it looks like this:

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
  <%=link_to pin_path(pin) do %>
    <%= pin.description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have a method error saying that there is no method: each:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

And of course if I get rid of this each method: the page only render one pin from the two pins I want to render.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I didn't understand the part where you said render pin with id 2 and 3 on a page and render pins with id 4 and **4** on an other page. What are you exactly trying to do? What are those pages? How can you insert `app/views/pins/index.html.erb` in `app/views/pins/mypage.html.erb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `@pins` anywhere.

```
def mypage
   @pins = Pin.where(id: [2,3])
end
```